# abortBroadcast SMS doesn't work for kitkat +

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms

From Android 4.4 you cannot abort these broadcasts, any solution to abort incomming SMS for android 4.4 + ?

Answer (score 1):

Write a full SMS client, and have the user make your app be that SMS client. Otherwise, [you cannot prevent the user's chosen SMS client from receiving messages](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).